The first time a div slides down the child elements it contains appear first JQuery
I am making a website with JQuery, and I want a signup bar to slide down when I click a button. For some reason, when I first click it, the signup form appears before the div containing it slides down. The div contains the background color, so it is a very noticeable difference. I am using the following code to make the form slide up first and down last.
            if (signupBarDown) {
                $signup.slideUp();
                $login.slideUp();
            }

            $signupOrLoginDiv.slideToggle(400);

            if (!signupBarDown) {
                $signup.slideDown();
                $login.slideDown();
            }

            signupBarDown = !signupBarDown;

As I said before this works perfectly if its not the first time sliding down/up
I have no idea why this happens.
The forms are absolutely positioned which forced me to right this code to begin with, but I don't know why that would stop it from working the first time. signupBarDown also starts as false.
I tried changing the positioning to fixed, because positioning it absolutely changed the effects of the script before, but it is still the same.

It probably "works" first time as slideUp() takes 0 time if it's already hidden.   Hard to tell what "works" means from your text and without [mcve].

You should use the complete callback of slideUp - eg $login.slideUp(() => $login.slideDown(() => $signupOrLoginDiv.slideDown()));     (but hard to tell from the text what $signUpOrLoginDiv is and when it should be shown - odd to put it as a .toggle between slideup/down)

I found out why this was happening. It needs to be hidden from the start of the code or by default in css. Otherwise, even though it takes 400ms to open, the website thinks it is open before it is completely open. Because of this, the forms show because the parent is no longer hidden. Adding $signup.hide() and $login.hide and the start of the $(document).ready function fixes this, because even though the parent is no longer hidden, the child still is. After this completes running, the second part showing the form runs, making it work.
